# How to add Notes Explorer of Microsoft Outlook in a windows application

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-2007, windows

I want to add Notes explorer in a windows application that will interact with 3rd party web service to fetch notes and show in the notes explorer.

All this functionality will happen on a click of a button in my application.

Once I click the button, notes will be fetched from web service, and will be shown on notes explorer.

I searched Google a lot for this. All I can find is how to create new note, but I want the whole functionality of notes explorer.

Is this really possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question, its not possible at all : Ref : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/outlookdev/thread/7962e745-85a6-4b03-8ab1-2ad760c29315